# Laravel 5.8: Can you help me with this problem

Tags: php, laravel, session, e-commerce, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 to develop my Online Store. And in this store, every product has a field of `prd_delivery` and it can be set one of these values:

**city_free_delivery**

**country_free_delivery**

***null***

When it is *null*, it means that it does not have any free delivery type.

And when users select their products, these situations must be applied:

[image: capture]

Note that the row **City** means, if user lives at the city and the row **Country** means, if he lives at outside of city (villages).

These situations applies to `cart.blade.php`, so I tried this:

```
@if($conflicting  && ($prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'country_free_delivery'))
    @php
        Session::forget('city');
        Session::forget('city_country');
        Session::put('country' , '1')
    @endphp
@endif

@if($conflicting  && ($prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'city_free_delivery'))
    @php
        Session::forget('country');
        Session::put('city' , '2');
    @endphp
@endif

@if($conflicting  && ($prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'city_free_delivery' || $prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'country_free_delivery'))
    @php
        Session::forget('country');
        Session::forget('city');
        Session::forget('free_notfree');
        Session::put('city_country' , '0');
        Session::put('free_notfree','13');
    @endphp
@endif

@if($conflicting  && ($prd[0]->prd_delivery == '' || $prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'city_free_delivery' || $prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'country_free_delivery'))
    @php
        if((session('free_notfree') != '13')){
            Session::forget('country');
            Session::forget('city_country');
            Session::put('free_notfree' , '3');
        }
    @endphp
@endif
```

And at the Controller, I have this:

```
$conflicting = false;
$free_delivery = '';

if ($foundOrder != null) {
  foreach ($foundOrder as $key => $value) {
    $product = Product::with('uploaded')->wherePrdId($value->id)->select('*')->first();

    // Just put a check here in case you have some non-free delivery types
    if ($product->prd_delivery == 'city_free_delivery' || $product->prd_delivery == 'country_free_delivery') {

      // Check if cart already have free delivery item and it conflict with current looping product or not
      if ($free_delivery && $free_delivery != $product->prd_delivery) {
        $conflicting = true;
      }

      $free_delivery = $product->prd_delivery;
    }

    $prds[] = [
       $product,
       $value->quantity,
       $value->price
    ];
  }
} else {
    $prds = [];
}
...
return view('frontend.shop.carts.index', compact('conflicting', ...));
```

So by this way I can check price of delivery (it can be free or not free), depends on the user location and user cart products.

For example at `checkout.blade.php`, if he's location is `city`, this will run

```
@if(Session()->has('city') || Session()->has('city_country') || Session()->has('country'))
    Free
@else
    {{ $item->price . ' Dollar'}}
@endif
```

Finally, the situations work fine but except the last one which is this:

[image]

In fact, it shows FREE to users, while the `{{ $item->price . ' Dollar'}}` must be shown!

So how to print price at the last situation ?

I know this question was a little but confusing, but I tried to explain the problem the best way. Because I'm on my wits with this.

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are setting session value inside a loop so only last loop value applied. With this requirement, you can create an array to store all delivery types of products in the cart then set session value depend on that array. And you should put your session setting logic in controller, not view.

```
$delivery_types = [];
$conflicting = false;

if ($foundOrder != null) {
  foreach ($foundOrder as $key => $value) {
    $product = Product::with('uploaded')->wherePrdId($value->id)->select('*')->first();

    array_push($delivery_types, $product->prd_delivery);

    $prds[] = [
       $product,
       $value->quantity,
       $value->price
    ];
  }

  $delivery_types = array_unique($delivery_types);

  // Your conflicting check here
  if (in_array('country_free_delivery', $delivery_types) && in_array('city_free_delivery', $delivery_types)) {
     $conflicting = true;
  }

  // Free logic check here
  if (in_array(null, $delivery_types)) {
     Session::put('free' , 'no');
  } else if (in_array('country_free_delivery', $delivery_types)) {
     Session::put('free' , 'country');
  } else {
     Session::put('free' , 'city');
  }

} else {
    $prds = [];
}
...
```

And then in your `checkout.blade.php`:

```
@if (session('free') == 'no)
  {{ $item->price . ' Dollar'}}
@else
  // Depend on user's location
@endIf
```

Comment: You are right buddy, but the problem is some sessions from other conditions are still submitted !

Comment: What are these sessions? Can you give more details?

Comment: Please if you know, let me know, I don't really know what to do and how to solve it